# Sass parent selector and hover?

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to trigger a parent's class when on hover? 
I know it can be done with jquery but I want to do a pure css solution.

My code:

```
.navbar-form{
    padding-left: 55px;
    .input-group{
        width: 200px;
        .form-control{
            border-right: none;
            width: 350px;
             &:hover & {
                border-color: blue;
            }
        }
        .input-group-addon{
            background-color: white;
            border-left: none;
        }
    }
}
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/fcKyc/

Looking to have that when I focus on the `input`, `.input-group-addon` would do something. `input` and the icon are children of the input-group.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fcKyc/

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add information. Don't put it in the comments if it is important.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand it right, here is my interpretation of the DOM interaction you're describing.

.parent

- .child1
- .child2

A hover on .child1 affects .child2

If yeah, then here:

```
.form-control {
    ... //your CSS for this
    input {
        //CSS for input
        &:hover ~ .input-group-addon {
            //CSS for .input-group-addon when input is hovered
        }
    }
}
```

OR, if `.input-group-addon` is right after `input` (adjacent sibling), then you could use the following:

```
.form-control {
    ... //your CSS for this
    input {
        //CSS for input
        &:hover + .input-group-addon {
            //CSS for .input-group-addon when input is hovered
        }
    }
}
```

As @Martin suggested.

Comment: +1 for the [**sibling combinator**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#sibling-combinators). You could also just use the `+` (adjacent sibling combinator) if you only want the sibling immediately after. See more here (works already in SCC2): [http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

Comment: @Martin Thank you, I noted that in the answer. (Not sure what the etiquette is when someone adds info to my answer via comment, so do tell me if I should've done something else.)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.navbar {
  background: #000;
  &:hover .change{
    background: #ccc;
  }
}
</style>

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="change">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you hover above the navbar then the .change div will change colors. This is what I usually use instead of using jQuery for certain effect triggers.

Comment: Yes, this works great if change is the child of navbar. I am looking to hover over change1 and have something done to change2 which are both children of navbar