# In SASS, How to refer tag select?

Tags: sass

In SASS's class selecter, I want to select parent's sibling.

```
.bw-textarea {
    height: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: white;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    color: #666666;

// textarea:disabled & {
//        background: #efefef;
//    }
}
```

Compiled above sass code,

```
.bw-textarea textarea:disabled {
    background: #efefef;
}
```

But I want to show result like this css code...

How to select like this in sass?

```
textarea.bw-textarea:disabled {
    background: #efefef;
}
```

Comment: I made mixin for this. Here my another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293891/sass-css-target-parent-class-from-child/49426503#49426503

Answer (score 3):

You gotta use `@root` in this case. It's pretty simple

This [**link**](http://sassbreak.com/getting-back-to-our-roots/) will give a clear idea about this selector

```
.bw-textarea {
  @at-root textarea#{&}:disabled{
    background: cyan;
  }
}
```

This will compile to

```
textarea.bw-textarea:disabled {
  background: cyan;
}
```

**[See this PEN](http://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/ZeavPO)**

Comment: '@at-root' is a really great tool but its overkill for this problem

Answer (score 2):

This is what your looking for:

```
.bw-textarea {
    height: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: white;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    color: #666666;

    &:disabled {
         background: #efefef;
    }
}
```

Check out this SO answer for a lil more idea on the nested pseudo selectors

[Sass parent selector and hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139182/sass-parent-selector-and-hover)

And of course check the sass docs

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

Comment: This is the correct answer for ease of use and writing less code.